# Translate django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I try to translate [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) messages in my project. I have created my translation files. But my translate don't use for any transable sentence that exists in django-allath by default. Look at here:

```
#: templates/account/logout.html:10
msgid "Are you sure you want to sign out?" # there are in django-allauth
msgstr "مطمئنی می‌خواهی خارج شوی؟"

#: templates/account/logout.html:20
msgid "Cancel" # there aren't in django-allauth
msgstr "لغو"
```

I get a thing like this in output:

Are you sure you want to sign out? -> the output isn't what I am looking for. there are this sentence in django-allauth.

Cancel -> the output is what I am looking for. there aren't this sentence in django-allauth

Here is my `setting.py`:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa-IR'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]

LANGUAGES = [
    ('fa', _('Persian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```